# Configure Broadleaf with Terracotta

Tags: spring-boot, broadleaf-commerce, terracotta, ehcache-2

How to configure the broadleaf demo with Terracotta 4.3.6?

EhCache version I am using in broadleaf is 2.10.4.
Broadleaf demo version is 5.2.0-GA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the Terracotta server from this [link](http://www.terracotta.org/open-source/).
Start the server using the start-tc-server.bat file available in path "server\bin".

Add the following code in the parent pom.xml

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>terracotta-repository</id>
        <url>http://www.terracotta.org/download/reflector/releases</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

In core, add the below dependencies in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache-terracotta</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.terracotta</groupId>
    <artifactId>terracotta-toolkit-1.5-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.terracotta</groupId>
    <artifactId>terracotta-toolkit-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

To override broadleaf ehcache add below code in your service configuration

```
@Merge("blMergedCacheConfigLocations")
public List<String> adminOverrideCache() {
    return Arrays.asList("classpath:bl-override-ehcache.xml");
}
```

Add the file "bl-override-ehcache.xml" in your classpath, with below code

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd" updateCheck="true"
    monitoring="autodetect">

<!-- Terracota server url -->
    <terracottaConfig url="localhost:9510" />

</ehcache>
```